# DSX images generated by pixiedust display command are ugly

Tags: dsx, data-science-experience, pixiedust

Any ideas why the display command in DSX gives such ugly image unlike the ones in Databricks? Plus I don't see that I can even add a hue color (even default) is ok like Databricks.

### Databricks

[image: Databricks display command image]

### Data Science Experience

[image: Data Science Experience Display command image]

Comment: Could you please add the actual commands to your question? The screenshots may be gone one day, while the question still remains useful. Also, mentioning the programming language of your notebooks would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. PixieDust is still in beta mode and the team is working hard toward 1.0 (next month or so). I've opened an issue on PixieDust repo so we make sure it will get addressed: https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pixiedust/issues/77

Answer (score 1):

As per David Taieb's comment, this has been acknowledged as an issue: https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pixiedust/issues/77

I've added David's comment as an answer so that the question can be closed (by accepting this answer).  Future discussions around this should now take place on the github issue.

Comment: Enhancements have been made to provide better formatting which should address this issue. You can get more details in the PixieDust doc site: https://ibm-cds-labs.github.io/pixiedust. Please upgrade to PixieDust v0.83 or higher to validate changes. Agreed that any new feedback should be taken to github.